# Python: How to know the number of row of a text file

Tags: python

I want to know the number of row of a text file. 
How can I do this?

Comment: You read it and count the lines.  Where you expecting some magic?

Comment: @Ben:  As @SpliFF commented on @horhay.romero's answer, your question isn't clear.  Do you want the total number of lines in the file, or the number of a given line.

Answer (score 4):

if iterating over a file:

```
for line_no, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
```

or if counting the lines in a file (`f`):

```
count = sum( 1 for line in f )
```

Comment: enumerate() will start counting with 0, which may not be what you want.  Also, file is the name of a function (equivalent to open()), so it's best not to use it as a variable name.

Comment: Fixed that. In python 2.6 and later, I believe, you can provide a number to start at.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = open('textfile.txt', 'rb')
len(f.readlines())
```

readlines() method returns a list where each index holds a line of textfile.txt.

Comment: although `sum( 1 for line in f )` would use less memory as it wouldn't load the entire file into memory.

Comment: The sample code just gives the total number of lines in the file.  I think the question is about getting the number of any given line.

Comment: @GreenMatt: the question is ambiguous. either way you interpret it the grammar is wrong. it should be either "the number of *rows*" or the "number of *a* row".

Comment: @SpliFF:  You're correct, although on first reading I didn't see it as ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("file.text")
count = sum(1 for line in f)
```

which is equivalent to

```
count = 0
for line in f:
   count+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan D. said, you can use [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) on the open file.  The default is to start counting with 0, so if you want to start the line count at 1 (or something else), use the `start` argument when calling enumerate().  Also, it's considered poor practice to use "file" as a variable name, as there is a [function by that name](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file).  Thus, try something like:

```
for line_no, line in enumerate(open(file_name), start=1):
    print line_no, line
```

Comment: Using the "file" function is semi-deprecated: """When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking this constructor directly"""